# How to include a specific association in sequelize findAll?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've created a database with two tables, Users and Points. A user can have many points and a point stores the ID of the user who sent it and the user who received it. I am trying to query for a table grouped by user showing the sum of the amounts of all their points, which is working querying raw in postgresql but not in sequelize.

**Working in postgresql:**

[image: postgresql query]

**Creating the models with sequelize:**

```
User.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    telegram_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: "users",
    sequelize: sequelize, // this bit is important
  }
);

Point.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      amount: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      to_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      from_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      tableName: "points",
      sequelize: sequelize, // this bit is important
    }
  );

User.hasMany(Point, {
  sourceKey: "telegram_id",
  foreignKey: "to_id",
  as: "recievedPoints", // this determines the name in `associations`!
});

User.hasMany(Point, {
  sourceKey: "telegram_id",
  foreignKey: "from_id",
  as: "sentPoints", // this determines the name in `associations`!
});

Point.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: "to_id",
  targetKey: "telegram_id",
  as: "toUser",
});
Point.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: "from_id",
  targetKey: "telegram_id",
  as: "fromUser",
});
```

**Attempting to make same query with sequelize:**

```
  const points = await Point.findAll({
    attributes: [
      "users.name",
      "points.to_id",
      [Sequelize.fn("SUM", Sequelize.col("points.amount")), "points.amount"],
    ],
    include: ["toUser"],
    group: ["users.name", "points.to_id"],
  });
```

**Resulting error:**

> SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "users"

**SQL generated by sequelize:**

```
SELECT "users"."name", "points"."to_id", SUM("points"."amount") AS "points.amount", "toUser"."id" AS "toUser.id", "toUser"."telegram_id" AS "toUser.telegram_id", "toUser"."name" AS "toUser.name", "toUser"."createdAt" AS "toUser.createdAt", "toUser"."updatedAt" AS "toUser.updatedAt" FROM "points" AS "Point" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" AS "toUser" ON "Point"."to_id" = "toUser"."telegram_id" GROUP BY "users"."name", "points"."to_id";
```

Comment: Please post the raw query generated by code.

Comment: Updated to include the generated query

Comment: chnage `"users.name",` to `"toUser.name",` , and try again

Comment: Just tried that and am getting this similar error: `ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "points"
LINE 1: SELECT "toUser"."name", "points"."to_id", SUM("points"."amou... HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "Point".`

Comment: Change `"points.to_id",` to `"Point.to_id",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RAW QUERY :**

```
SELECT "users"."name", "points"."to_id", SUM("points"."amount") AS "points.amount", "toUser"."id" AS "toUser.id", "toUser"."telegram_id" AS "toUser.telegram_id", "toUser"."name" AS "toUser.name", "toUser"."createdAt" AS "toUser.createdAt", "toUser"."updatedAt" AS "toUser.updatedAt" 
FROM "points" AS "Point" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" AS "toUser" ON "Point"."to_id" = "toUser"."telegram_id" GROUP BY "users"."name", "points"."to_id";
```

As per your raw query :

Change **"users" to "toUser"** every where

Change **"points" to "Point"** every where , like this :

```
const points = await Point.findAll({
    attributes: [
        "toUser.name",
        "Point.to_id",
        [Sequelize.fn("SUM", Sequelize.col("Point.amount")), "Point.amount"],
    ],
    include: ["toUser"],
    group: ["toUser.name", "Point.to_id"],
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the query running with this

Comment: You don't need to specify `toUser.name` attribute, since it's added by `Sequelize` in scope of `include: ['toUser']`

Comment: Yes, but he is not defining in it, else I would have suggested that